# How to tell for which object attribute pickle fails?

Tags: python, serialization

When you pickle an object that has some attributes which cannot be pickled it will fail with a generic error message like:

```
PicklingError: Can't pickle <type 'instancemethod'>: attribute lookup __builtin__.instancemethod failed
```

Is there any way to tell which attribute caused the exception? I am using Python 2.5.2.

Even though I understand in principle the root cause of the problem (e.g. in the above example having an instance method) it can still be very hard to *exactly pinpoint it*. In my case I already defined a custom `__getstate__` method, but forgot about a critical attribute. This happened in a complicated structure of nested objects, so it took me a while to identify the bad attribute.

As requested, here is one simple example were pickle intentionally fails:

```
import cPickle as pickle
import new

class Test(object):
    pass

def test_func(self):
    pass

test = Test()
pickle.dumps(test)
print "now with instancemethod..."
test.test_meth = new.instancemethod(test_func, test)
pickle.dumps(test)
```

This is the output:

```
now with instancemethod...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/wilbert/develop/workspace/Playground/src/misc/picklefail.py", line 15, in <module>
    pickle.dumps(test)
  File "/home/wilbert/lib/python2.5/copy_reg.py", line 69, in _reduce_ex
    raise TypeError, "can't pickle %s objects" % base.__name__
TypeError: can't pickle instancemethod objects
```

Unfortunately there is no hint that the attribute `test_meth` causes the problem.

Comment: can you maybe give a small example of a failing attribute? or at least show a bit more of the traceback to see where in the pickle module it fails?

Comment: oh, and which Python version are you using?

Comment: @MrTopf: added the information

Comment: thanks, but actually I think your only choice is indeed patching (and filing a bug report).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You could file a bug against Python for not including more helpful error messages. In the meantime, modify the `_reduce_ex()` function in `copy_reg.py`.

```
if base is self.__class__:
    print self # new   
    raise TypeError, "can't pickle %s objects" % base.__name__
```

Output:

```
<bound method ?.test_func of <__main__.Test object at 0xb7f4230c>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "nopickle.py", line 14, in ?
    pickle.dumps(test)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/copy_reg.py", line 69, in _reduce_ex
    raise TypeError, "can't pickle %s objects" % base.__name__
TypeError: can't pickle instancemethod objects
```

Comment: why not simply putting "self" into the error message instead of the print?

Comment: I believe this covers the "TypeError" exception in the example, however the original "PicklingError" exception is not addressed.

Comment: The TypeError causes the PicklingError. Once you stop trying to pickle instancemethod objects (or any other non-pickleable object) everything should work.

Comment: I think this should be part of Python, or at least merged in with the raise statement.

Comment: It's hard to believe the accepted answer is to modify the python distribution and recompile. (1) You can do the same thing without modifying python, and (2) if you are going to do such a thing, at least submit a patch to python.

Comment: @MikeMcKerns and how can we do this without modifying Python? I cannot change a 3rd party that uses pickle and now I want to see which attribute is causing me error.

Comment: @dashesy: mine and the other two answers are all viable methods to find which attribute(s) cause the pickling error.  `dill.detect` can be used to check which objects fail to pickle with `dill`.  If the library you are interested in uses `pickle`, and you want to use `dill`… just type `import dill` and it will load `dill` registered types into the  `pickle` registry… without editing the 3rd party code.  If you want to use `dill` to detect errors, but not augment python's `pickle` module… then type: `dill.extend(False)`.

Comment: @MikeMcKerns that is very useful, did not know `dill` will do that, thanks. Do you know if this also works for `cPickle`?

Comment: @dashesy: I'm the `dill` author… and no. `dill` can't augment the `cPickle` registry.  That's the main reason I forked `multiprocessing` to `pathos`.

Answer (score 10):

I had the same problem as you, but my classes were a bit more complicated (i.e. a large tree of similar objects) so the printing didn't help much so I hacked together a helper function. It is not complete and is only intended for use with pickling protocol 2:
It was enough so I could locate my problems. If you want to extend it to cover everything, the protocol is described at http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0307/ i've made this post editable so everybody can update the code.

```
import pickle
def get_pickling_errors(obj,seen=None):
    if seen == None:
        seen = []
    try:
        state = obj.__getstate__()
    except AttributeError:
        return
    if state == None:
        return
    if isinstance(state,tuple):
        if not isinstance(state[0],dict):
            state=state[1]
        else:
            state=state[0].update(state[1])
    result = {}    
    for i in state:
        try:
            pickle.dumps(state[i],protocol=2)
        except pickle.PicklingError:
            if not state[i] in seen:
                seen.append(state[i])
                result[i]=get_pickling_errors(state[i],seen)
    return result
```

An example of the usage where K is the object that doesn't pickle

```
>>> get_pickling_errors(K)
{'_gen': {}, '_base': {'_gens': None}}
```

This means that the attibute K._gen is not picklable and the same goes for K._base._gens.

Comment: Thanks, it helps. And I think `__getstate__()` should defined in corresponding Class.

Answer (score 4):

I have found that if you subclass Pickler and wrap the Pickler.save() method in a try, except block

```
import pickle
class MyPickler (pickle.Pickler):
    def save(self, obj):
        try:
            pickle.Pickler.save(self, obj)
        except Exception, e:
            import pdb;pdb.set_trace()
```

Then call it like so

```
import StringIO
output = StringIO.StringIO()
MyPickler(output).dump(thingee)
```

Comment: Isn't this just starting a debugger? Is there any difference to, e.g., just using the Eclipse PyDev Debugger to look at the problem?

Comment: If the PyDev debugger will start up on the exception and put you in the right level of execution, it is the same. I don't use an IDE though.

Comment: I used this to locate a particularly difficult-to-find Pickle error. But rather than having the except clause start the debugger, I just had it print obj and raise the exception. Then, running the MyPickler(output).dump(obj) resulted in a nice traceback-like report of exactly where the unpickleable object was in my deeply-nested structures. What a day.

Answer (score 4):

If you use `dill`, your example doesn't fail to pickle...

```
>>> import dill
>>> import new
>>> 
>>> class Test(object):
...     pass
... 
>>> def test_func(self):
...     pass
... 
>>> test = Test()
>>> dill.dumps(test)
'\x80\x02cdill.dill\n_create_type\nq\x00(cdill.dill\n_load_type\nq\x01U\x08TypeTypeq\x02\x85q\x03Rq\x04U\x04Testq\x05h\x01U\nObjectTypeq\x06\x85q\x07Rq\x08\x85q\t}q\n(U\r__slotnames__q\x0b]q\x0cU\n__module__q\rU\x08__main__q\x0eU\x07__doc__q\x0fNutq\x10Rq\x11)\x81q\x12}q\x13b.'
>>> test.test_meth = new.instancemethod(test_func, test)
>>> dill.dumps(test)
'\x80\x02cdill.dill\n_create_type\nq\x00(cdill.dill\n_load_type\nq\x01U\x08TypeTypeq\x02\x85q\x03Rq\x04U\x04Testq\x05h\x01U\nObjectTypeq\x06\x85q\x07Rq\x08\x85q\t}q\n(U\r__slotnames__q\x0b]q\x0cU\n__module__q\rU\x08__main__q\x0eU\x07__doc__q\x0fNutq\x10Rq\x11)\x81q\x12}q\x13U\ttest_methq\x14h\x01U\nMethodTypeq\x15\x85q\x16Rq\x17cdill.dill\n_create_function\nq\x18(cdill.dill\n_unmarshal\nq\x19Ubc\x01\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00C\x00\x00\x00s\x04\x00\x00\x00d\x00\x00S(\x01\x00\x00\x00N(\x00\x00\x00\x00(\x01\x00\x00\x00t\x04\x00\x00\x00self(\x00\x00\x00\x00(\x00\x00\x00\x00s\x07\x00\x00\x00<stdin>t\t\x00\x00\x00test_func\x01\x00\x00\x00s\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01q\x1a\x85q\x1bRq\x1cc__builtin__\n__main__\nU\ttest_funcq\x1dNN}q\x1etq\x1fRq h\x12N\x87q!Rq"sb.'
```

So we have to find something that `dill` can't pickle...

```
>>> class Unpicklable(object):
...   def breakme(self):
...     self.x = iter(set())
... 
>>> u = Unpicklable()
>>> dill.dumps(u)
'\x80\x02cdill.dill\n_create_type\nq\x00(cdill.dill\n_load_type\nq\x01U\x08TypeTypeq\x02\x85q\x03Rq\x04U\x0bUnpicklableq\x05h\x01U\nObjectTypeq\x06\x85q\x07Rq\x08\x85q\t}q\n(U\r__slotnames__q\x0b]q\x0cU\n__module__q\rU\x08__main__q\x0eU\x07breakmeq\x0fcdill.dill\n_create_function\nq\x10(cdill.dill\n_unmarshal\nq\x11U\xafc\x01\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00C\x00\x00\x00s"\x00\x00\x00d\x01\x00d\x00\x00l\x00\x00}\x01\x00t\x01\x00t\x02\x00\x83\x00\x00\x83\x01\x00|\x00\x00_\x03\x00d\x00\x00S(\x02\x00\x00\x00Ni\xff\xff\xff\xff(\x04\x00\x00\x00t\t\x00\x00\x00itertoolst\x04\x00\x00\x00itert\x03\x00\x00\x00sett\x01\x00\x00\x00x(\x02\x00\x00\x00t\x04\x00\x00\x00selfR\x00\x00\x00\x00(\x00\x00\x00\x00(\x00\x00\x00\x00s\x07\x00\x00\x00<stdin>t\x07\x00\x00\x00breakme\x02\x00\x00\x00s\x04\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x0c\x01q\x12\x85q\x13Rq\x14c__builtin__\n__main__\nh\x0fNN}q\x15tq\x16Rq\x17U\x07__doc__q\x18Nutq\x19Rq\x1a)\x81q\x1b}q\x1cb.'
>>> u.breakme()
>>> dill.dumps(u)
Traceback (most recent call last):
…(snip)… 
pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <type 'setiterator'>: it's not found as __builtin__.setiterator
>>>
```

If the error message wasn't good, I could use `dill.detect` to see which what unpicklable objects the top-level object contains.

```
>>> dill.detect.badobjects(u, depth=1)
{'__hash__': <method-wrapper '__hash__' of Unpicklable object at 0x10a37b350>, '__setattr__': <method-wrapper '__setattr__' of Unpicklable object at 0x10a37b350>, '__reduce_ex__': <built-in method __reduce_ex__ of Unpicklable object at 0x10a37b350>, '__reduce__': <built-in method __reduce__ of Unpicklable object at 0x10a37b350>, '__str__': <method-wrapper '__str__' of Unpicklable object at 0x10a37b350>, '__format__': <built-in method __format__ of Unpicklable object at 0x10a37b350>, '__getattribute__': <method-wrapper '__getattribute__' of Unpicklable object at 0x10a37b350>, '__delattr__': <method-wrapper '__delattr__' of Unpicklable object at 0x10a37b350>, 'breakme': <bound method Unpicklable.breakme of <__main__.Unpicklable object at 0x10a37b350>>, '__repr__': <method-wrapper '__repr__' of Unpicklable object at 0x10a37b350>, '__dict__': {'x': <setiterator object at 0x10a370820>}, 'x': <setiterator object at 0x10a370820>, '__sizeof__': <built-in method __sizeof__ of Unpicklable object at 0x10a37b350>, '__init__': <method-wrapper '__init__' of Unpicklable object at 0x10a37b350>}
>>> dill.detect.badtypes(u, depth=1)
{'__hash__': <type 'method-wrapper'>, '__setattr__': <type 'method-wrapper'>, '__reduce_ex__': <type 'builtin_function_or_method'>, '__reduce__': <type 'builtin_function_or_method'>, '__str__': <type 'method-wrapper'>, '__format__': <type 'builtin_function_or_method'>, '__getattribute__': <type 'method-wrapper'>, '__delattr__': <type 'method-wrapper'>, 'breakme': <type 'instancemethod'>, '__repr__': <type 'method-wrapper'>, '__dict__': <type 'dict'>, 'x': <type 'setiterator'>, '__sizeof__': <type 'builtin_function_or_method'>, '__init__': <type 'method-wrapper'>}
>>> set(dill.detect.badtypes(u, depth=1).values())
set([<type 'dict'>, <type 'method-wrapper'>, <type 'instancemethod'>, <type 'setiterator'>, <type 'builtin_function_or_method'>])
```

`dill` doesn't rely on the `__getstate__` method being present, although maybe it should utilize it if it exists.  You can also use `objgraph` to get a picture of all the object dependencies that are used to build the thing that doesn't pickle.  It can help you sort out what the root of the problem is, based on the above information.

See `dill.detect` use in tracking down unpicklable items in this issue: https://github.com/uqfoundation/dill/issues/58

Answer (score 0):

I was puzzled as well by the general error..
Digging a bit more, the doc explains how class instances are pickled https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#pickling-class-instances

Based on doc, I implemented the following util to understand which attributes are causing problems while pickling a custom object `obj`

```
def pickle_get_attributes(obj):
    return obj.__class__, obj.__dict__


def pickle_restore_attributes(cls, attributes):
    obj = cls.__new__(cls)
    obj.__dict__.update(attributes)
    return obj


def check_if_pickle(obj):
    obj_class, obj_attrs_dict = pickle_get_attributes(obj)

    obj_attrs_dict["__class__"] = obj_class

    for nm, attr in obj_attrs_dict.items():
        print(f"{nm} {type(attr)}")
        try:
            pickle_str = pickle.dumps(attr)
        except TypeError as e:
            print(f"CANNOT PICKLE {nm} of type {type(attr)}")

check_if_pickle(obj)
```