# Celery tasks with unpickable arguments

Tags: python, celery, message-queue, mq, google-ads-api

I'm trying to implement a messaging queue system to push operations to the AdWords API.

```
 class Call(object):
    @celery.task(filter=task_method)
    def MUTATE(self, operations):
        assert hasattr(self, '__throwaway_service')
        with self.__throwaway_service as sm:
            response = sm.mutate(operations)
        return response
```

since I cannot use the service instance as an argument (service has methods to send 'get' or 'mutate' requests to the API), i set it as external attribute and delete it when all the operations for that specific service are sent to the MQ.

'operations' is a list of dictionaries containing string or unicode keys and values.

I still get

```
PicklingError: Can't pickle <type 'instancemethod'>: attribute lookup __builtin__.instancemethod failed
```

Am I getting this error because the celery task is using an instance method at all? What is the best and pythonic way to implement this?

Comment: I think the problem is that your task method is inside a class, could you try to convert your "MUTATE" method in a plain python function and test it that way to see if it works?

Comment: Well, the problem is the service instance. I need that cos it's on that service that I push the operations. So if I have the method as function, service has to be an argument, and it can't because it's not pickable. Nothing changes with the class unfortunately. I'm just stuck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To run this `MUTATE` task, an instance of `Call` must be passed to queue. I suppose your Call, containing fancy methods such as `__throwaway_service` hardly is pickable. So you'd have to redesign your task, reconstructing `self` object in a task and applying original `MUTATE` afterwards.

Also, you might find [this reciepe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/570910/1265154) useful to find out what exactly object can't be pickled.

**update**

Is this pattern applicable:

```
@celery.task
def mutate(service_settings, operations):
    service = Service(**service_settings)
    return service.mutate(operations)
```

Comment: I'm stuck. How would you redesign this task? I need a service instance, that I assume is the unpickable part, and operations to push to this service. I really can't think of another way that doesn't have the service as instance attribute or task argument

Comment: How do you instantiate this instance? Is it just api wrapper with some auth params? Can you provide more details on your classes/instances.

Comment: The class with MUTATE is a parent class, without __init__. It collects operations (and related service) from a number of subclasses. Once all the operations are collected I want to call the MUTATE method for each pair servce-operations, and send that to the queue. Should I put the MUTATE method in a isolated class instance?

Comment: See updates to the answer. I'm not sure I understood you well, you'd better add some code sample.

Comment: Yes, I needed to change quite a lot of code down the hierarchy, but basically I was getting the service instances too early at runtime. Now instead of a service instance I pass the arguments to get the service, and then the Caller instantiate the service within one of its methods.

Answer (score 0):

There is probably an object in operations. You need to process the object into dictionary or other native types before passing it to celery task.