# Difference between pickling an object piecewise vs all at once?

Tags: python, serialization, pickle

Given an arbitrary pythonic object like this:

```
class ExampleObj(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 'a'
        self.b = 'b'
        self.c = 'c'

obj = ExampleObj()
```

Is there any functional difference between these two serialization approaches?

**Piecewise Pickling**

```
base = type(obj)
name = obj.__class__.__name__
pickled_data = {}

for key,val in obj.__dict__.items():
    pickled_data[key] = pickle.dumps(val)

vars = {k : pickle.loads(v) for k,v in pickled_data.items()}
restored = type(name, (base,), vars)
```

**Standard Pickling**

```
restored = pickle.loads( pickle.dumps(obj) )
```

I can't envision any, but I'm worried there may be some edge case I'm not considering.

(In my application, some objects may not have serializable variables. We were hoping to implement piecewise pickling so we better identify what variables are preventing us from pickling the object)

Comment: Certainly there is a difference, as the first approach creates an instance of `type` (i.e. a class) while the second approach creates an instance of `ExampleObj`.

Comment: Can you clarify "functional difference?"

Comment: @WesDoyle I mean will code be able to interact with a peicewise restored object identically to a standard unpickle?

Comment: You might consider looking at the package `dill`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first case, you're creating an instance of `type`, whereas in the second case, you're creating an instance of the type `ExampleObj`.  To see how the two results are functionally different, I'll name `restored_1` the result of your first example, and `restored_2` the second.

```
type(restored_1)  # type
type(restored_2)  # __main__.ExampleObj
```

Thus, `restored_1` and `restored_2` will not be functionally equivalent in the sense that you mention you're looking for.

As a simple illustration, add a method or property to `ExampleObj` and try to use the restored object from either procedure in various ways.

```
class ExampleObj(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 'a'
        self.b = 'b'
        self.c = 'c'

    def foo(self):
        print('bar')

    @property
    def baz(self):
        print(self.a + self.b)

obj = ExampleObj()
```

After executing your first code, which returns an instance of `type`:

```
restored_1.foo()     # exception raised because restored_1 is not an ExampleObj instance
restored_1.bar       # returns <property at 0x107863138> type
restored_1.__dict__  # returns a mappingproxy object
```

After executing your second code, which returns an instance of `ExampleObj`:

```
restored_2.foo()     # bar
restored_2.bar       # ab
restored_2.__dict__  # {'a': 'a', 'b': 'b', 'c': 'c'}
```

If you're looking for a discussion on approaches to see for which instance attrs pickling failed, see this question: [How to tell for which object attribute pickle fails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/569754/how-to-tell-for-which-object-attribute-pickle-fails)